# Salesforce trial org: no more storage due to "Interaction Count Reports"

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-chatter

In the "Storage usage" page, under "Setup", I can see that Storage is full because of "Interaction Count Reports". They take 81% of the space but I cannot find them anywhere. There is no custom object with that name and there are no reports under the reports tab.
So, I don't know how to delete them if I cannot even find them. Of course Salesforce cannot help on that and I cannot open a case as this is a trial account. Also cannot create a new org as there is a lot of configuration which is hard to migrate. Any idea on a possible solution to this?

Comment: What do you get when you `SELECT Id FROM InteractionCountReport`? Are you able to use something like https://workbench.developerforce.com/ to run a describe? Do you think you have lots of Chatter posts (FeedItem) you may have to delete?

Comment: Check your profile/permission sets. Is this thing there in Object Permissions? Maybe you need to make it readable (and a tab too if there's any) to see it?

Comment: That query returns "INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'InteractionCountReport' is not supported.". Also, I'm system administrator and in the profile all permissions that can be enabled are enabled.